# Play Framework: How to convert JSON to List[Int]

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON string...

```
val jsonStr = "[1, 2, 3]"
```

... how do I convert it into a `List[Int]`? The following statement returns a `JsValue`, which does not contain method `read`:

```
Json.parse(jsonStr)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play provides several ways to decode JSON. The "simplest" is `as`:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val jsonStr = "[1, 2, 3]"
jsonStr: String = [1, 2, 3]

scala> val json = Json.parse(jsonStr)
json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [1,2,3]

scala> val xs = json.as[List[Int]]
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

This will throw an exception in the case that you don't actually have a list of integers, though, so it's generally a bad idea. `asOpt` and `validate` are much better:

```
scala> val xsMaybe = json.asOpt[List[Int]]
xsMaybe: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> val xsResult = json.validate[List[Int]]
xsResult: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[List[Int]] = JsSuccess(List(1, 2, 3),)
```

Now you're forced by the type system to deal with the possibility of error, which means fewer surprises at runtime.

All of these methods take an implicit `Reads[_]` argument. Play provides instances for `Reads[Int]` and `Reads[List[A: Reads]]` out of the box, and you can get the same syntax for your own types by defining your own `Reads` instances.

Comment: ... I used asInstanceOf[] instead of as[]... and that's why my code didn't work. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Right—the naming of `as` and `asOpt` is a little unfortunate, since they don't really have anything to do with casting.